# C# - How to scan Interleaved 2 of 5 with more than 10 digits? Motorola EMDK 2.6 .NET on MC55 running Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, barcode, motorola

I am currently struggling to get the Motorola MC55 to read Interleaved 2 of 5 barcodes with more than 10 digits.

I have gone through the help file for the Motorola EMDK .NET 2.6 but I could not figure out how to increase the maximum barcode length.

Here is some sample code in C#:

```
// Create reader
this.MyReader = new Symbol.Barcode.Reader();

// Create reader data
this.MyReaderData = new Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData(
    Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataTypes.Text,
    Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);

// I can read the maximum length of I2of5 but I don't know how to set
// Output is 10
MessageBox.Show(this.MyReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength.ToString());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting like below

```
SymbolReader.Decoders.I2OF5.Enabled = true;
SymbolReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength = 0;
SymbolReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength = 0;
```

I think '0' should set it to MAX. If it doesn't, try some big value.

I don't have any PDA to test.

References:

- SO [need help = using class with barcode scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611816/need-help-using-class-with-barcode-scanning)
- MSDN Forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/681ea982-f1a7-4cc2-9c5d-75c77c9f6ea9

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution. The tooltip in VS2008 says that those properties only return but do not set values. I guess now they do set ...